# Payment gateway upgrading issue in Nopcommerce3.0

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I have upgrade nocommerce version  2.3 to 3.0 but there is some  issue in Payment Gateway plugin well i think new version 3.0  there is missing  two dll (Tax.StrikeIron,Tax.Fixed.Rate)

[image: payment method there is seems not Payment method available]

Comment: Do you have any active payment plugins?

Comment: I got it i have configured plugin in admin panel then after i got it...  Thanks..!